# How to update all Documents in one Collection in Swift Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

How do I update all Documents in one collection at all without naming them directly.
This is my code:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
             
db.collection((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!).document().updateData(["status":""])

  {(err) in
     if err != nil {
 
                         
                         print("again failed")
                         return
                         
     }else{
         print("success")
     
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not have the equivalent of an SQL "update where" query.  You will have to perform a query to fetch all the documents, iterate the results, and update each document individually.  There are no shortcuts to this process if you don't know the document IDs ahead of time.